# Should I wake a newborn to feed?

Tags: sleep, newborn, feeding

My baby boy is 9 weeks old, he always drinks every 2 or 3 hours at day times. At night time he's always asleep more then 4 hours. I am afraid he is hungry. Should I wake him up to feed at night if he falls asleep longer then 3 hours?

Comment: http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/do-i-really-need-to-wake-my-newborn-to-feed-him?rq=1 answers your question better than I did.